# Evernote Share panel and HTML: my app vs. Mobile Safari

Tags: ios, evernote

Having strange issue with Evernote sharing in my app. When a user shares an web page, we provide a stripped down "light" version of the original HTML to the activity view controller. Included in this HTML is a `<title>` tag for the content.

The following text behaves differently in Mobile Safari sharing vs. my application:
`オーバーエイジ決定！ 藤春の得意技は「どんなボールでも、僕がナイスパスにしてあげる」 | サッカーダイジェストWeb`

When sharing a web page with the above  in Mobile Safari, the full title displays in the share panel. When sharing HTML with the above  in my app, only the text `オーバーエイジ決定！` displays. When I check my Evernote notebook, the headline has indeed been truncated at the `!` for my app's shared article; it is not just a display issue.

There is a space after the `!` and I have found that other  objects with a space immediately following a punctuation exhibits this odd behavior. The title displays properly in Mobile Safari when sharing to Evernote, but truncates at the punctuation for my app.

So, this leads to two questions:

1. When sharing HTML to the Evernote share panel via an activity view controller's activity items, is  the appropriate tag? Is there some evernote-specific tag I should be wrapping things in?
2. Is there any documentation about sharing web content to the Evernote share panel; i.e. best practices for consistent results.